# Why does my scooter (scooty streak) stop running?

Tags: stall, scooter

I had this problem a while ago and it only occurred very rarely and I mean extremely rarely, I just had my scooter patched up because there was some problem with the engine. Now after I got it repaired it stops every now and then, like at least twice everyday.

I took it back to the mechanic and they fixed it twice the second time they just adjusted some sort of screw, and it started fine. And the problem shows up again after like two days.

I was wondering if my mechanic had decided to replace my working part and put an old and worn out part. In the premise of fixing another problem?

Comment: Hi Adish Redd.Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say that. Did you get your scooter fixed by a reputed mechanic? If not its very much possible. Or he could have replaced the faulty part with a second hand part from another vehicle which he must be having already in his garage.

My advice would be to go to an authorised service centre and get your vehicle serviced/inspected there. It's costly, but you can have peace of mind and be assured that they would be using genuine and new parts always. Also, you can ask for the old parts which they will be replacing from your vehicle.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the op asks for the parts from the service centre? Has it been there yet? Or, do you mean go back to the original mechanic and ask for the parts?

Comment: I mean to say that for the next subsequent service from the authorised service station op can ask for old parts replaced for his vehicle.sorry for the confusion.I corrected my answer.